# Процентное соотношение языков веб-программирования

Tags: python, веб-программирование, php, ruby, lua

Какой процент веб-приложений в интернете написан с использованием таких языков как Python, Ruby и Lua? Есть ли смысл переходить с PHP на какой-либо из этих языков?

Comment: Google использует python ,youtube переписан на python google'ом  ,Instagram — python  Django. и т.д.
Github — Ruby on Rails. Изначально twitter — руби.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По Пайтону.
По моим наблюдениям, количество новых веб-ресурсов на Python, Ruby и остальных "набирающих моду" в вебе языков примерно равен количеству (или чуть меньше) написанных на старом добром РНР.
Переходить на Python однозначно стоит, потому как Python - очень гибкий и мощный язык с простым для понимания и структуирования синтаксисом, который быстро набирает популярность, и рано или поздно будет одним из лидеров в вебе, обойдя РНР. В приницпе он уже сейчас [дышит ему в спину](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html).
У меня есть много знакомых веб-разработчиков, перешедших с РНР на Python, и ни одного, кто бы сделал наоборот.
Думаю, не зря Python активно используют Yandex и Google.

Answer (score 2):

Lua - это язык не совсем для веба. Я вижу его применение в качестве средства автоматизации различных программ. А так язык хороший =)

Ruby или Python знать не обязательно - РНР ещё, как минимум, несколько лет будет широко распространён. Но, думаю, для кругозора и расширения инструментария полезно.

Что-то проще сделать на РНР, что-то - на других языках. Если знать их несколько (что не так и трудно), - будет замечательно. Тем более, что языки эти весьма многообещающие.

К тому же, Python применяется далеко не только в веб-программировании.

Answer (score 1):

Переходите на питон. Я пол года назад попробовал и до сих пор нарадоваться не могу. 
PHP хороший язык, не нужно идти на поводу всех этих гламурных лозунгов, типа "все пэхапэ прогеры - быдлокодеры". Если работаете в вебе, с PHP будете сталкиваться постоянно. А как откроете для себя Django - будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 1):

Python  набирает обороты - это факт, но переходить особого смысла не вижу (иначе бы сам давно перешел). 
Есть смысл переходить на более эффективные языки, такие как  С++, Java или Эрланг.
Хочу отметить Эрланг - высокопроизводительная платформа для распределенных приложений. Уже достатоточно много встроенного функционала для масштабирования приложений. Перспективен в WEB. Но это будет язык не написания странички "Васи Пупкина", а написания сервисов для социалок и прочих хайлоад сервисов.

Comment: Спасибо ответ, но C++ для меня не актуален, т.к. я занимаюсь исключительно скриптовым программированием, для интернета.

Comment: Скоко-скоко там в erlang'е строки-то занимают? По слову на символ, кажись, раньше-то было. Сейчас вряд ли меньше. Так что для обычных web-серверов это ещё тот инструмент...

Answer (score 1):

ПО данным на июнь: PHP на первом месте, но сдает позиции. Следом идет Python, который тоже немного начал падать в рейтинге. Далее - Lua, быстро набирает популярность. Самый последний из перечисленных вами - Ruby, теряет позиции.